# iOS - CLGeocoder without internet connection

Tags: ios, clgeocoder

I am using `CLGeocoder` to locate adresses on a map and calculate the user's distance in comparison to a whole bunch of adresses.

Here is the part of the code that uses `CLGeocoder`:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
__block float distance;
__block CLLocation *location;
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:adresseFinal completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        distance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
        [distanceArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", distance]];
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = coordinate;
        point.title = tableNoms[i];
        NSMutableArray *coords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [coords addObject:location];
        [coords addObject:userLocation];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];
```

But when I try and use it without internet connection, I get the following error:

> Could not determine current country code: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x7877f930 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x7877ed30 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}

I thought I was able to use localisation without internet (using GPS?)?

Do I have to change something in my code in order to be able to use it?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geocoding isn't the same as geolocation. The GPS is used to determine your geolocation and the result of that is a latitude/longitude position. Geocoding is the process of converting between that geolocation and the corresponding address details.

While geolocation doesn't require an Internet connection, geocoding does because it's a lookup on an Apple database to find the address for the geolocation.

Comment: Also, localisation is the process of allowing your app to use multiple languages and as such isn't related to physical locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is clear enough. Oh and my bad for localisation...stupid mistake. Thanks a lot !